# Json mal formado por funcion PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

Estoy armando un json en una función php y al tomarlo en js me da error al querer parsearlo.

Cuando lo validé en una pagina dice que es invalido, al borrarle:

> mesano"[]"

Puedo validarlo correctamente.

Alguna idea de como crear el json sin

> mesano"[]"

Esa es mi funcion php y la respuesta que genera.

```
PHP
    $resultado = "[";
                foreach($valores as $k=>$v){
                    $v["X"] = rounded($v["X"]);
                    $v["Y"] = rounded($v["Y"]);
                    $v["A"] = rounded($v["A"]);
                    $v["L"] = rounded($v["L"]);
                    $v["T"] = rounded($v["T"]);
                    $resultado .= "{dia:'".$k."',";
                    $resultado .= "X:'".number_format($v['X'])."',";
                    $resultado .= "Y:'".number_format($v['Y'])."',";
                    $resultado .= "A:'".number_format($v['A'])."',";
                    $resultado .= "L:'".number_format($v['L'])."',";
                    $resultado .= "T:'".number_format($v['T'])."'},";   
                } 
                $resultado = trim($resultado, ",");
                $resultado .= "]";  

                $retorno1 = $resultado;

Respuesta
    mesano"[{dia:'01-08-2016',X:'0',Y:'5',A:'38',L:'31',T:'35'}]"
```

Comment: Si tienes el array aquí `$valores`, ¿por qué no lo construyes con `$json=json_encode($valores)`. De esa manera tendrás en la variable `$json` un json creado por PHP. Ver **[`json_encode` en el Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php)**

Comment: Cuando envío directamente el `$valores`, el json se forma así, `(mesano{"01-08-2016":{"X":"2","Y":"3","A":"23","L":"14","T":"95"}})`. según https://jsonlint.com tampoco es un json valido. es por eso que cree la función para armar el json.

Comment: Es extraño, quizá estés tratando de re-inventar la rueda no solamente aquí,  sino también cuando construyes el array que viene en `$valores` y por eso estés teniendo problemas. Si `$valores` fuese un array cualquiera bien construido la función `json_encode` te construiría un json válido.

Comment: De todos modos, _casi_ te crea un json válido: `{
 "mesano": {
  "01-08-2016": {
   "X": "2",
   "Y": "3",
   "A": "23",
   "L": "14",
   "T": "95"
  }
 }
}` salvo la llave de apertura y cierre adicional, el valor `mesano` entre comillas y la eliminación de caracteres extraños que aparecen después del valor `"T":` por lo que es posible que no estés aplicando adecuadamente la codificación (generalmente utf-8).

Answer (score 0):

> El problema es que está malformado tu JSON, todos los strings incluídas las claves/llaves deben estar envueltas entre comillas dobles.

## Solución 1

```
$resultado = "[";
foreach($valores as $k=>$v){
    $resultado .= '{ "dia": "'.$k.'",';
    $resultado .= ' "Xv": "'.number_format(rounded($v["X"])).'",';
    $resultado .= ' "Y": "'.number_format(rounded($v["Y"])).'",';
    $resultado .= ' "A": "'.number_format(rounded($v["A"])).'",';
    $resultado .= ' "L": "'.number_format(rounded($v["L"])).'",';
    $resultado .= ' "T": "'.number_format(rounded($v["T"])).'"},'; 
}
$resultado = trim($resultado, ",");
$resultado .= "]";  

$retorno1 = $resultado;
```

## Solución 2

```
$valores = ...;
$resultados = [];

foreach($valores as $key => $value) {
  $resultado = [
    "dia" => $key,
    "Xv" => number_format(rounded($value["X"])),
    "Y" => number_format(rounded($value["Y"])),
    "A" => number_format(rounded($value["A"])),
    "L" => number_format(rounded($value["L"])),
    "T" => number_format(rounded($value["T"]))
  ];
  array_push($resultados, (object) $resultado);
}

$json = json_encode($resultados, true);
```

Comment: existe alguna diferencia significativa entre dejarlas con dobles comillas o con comilla simple??

Comment: Sí, que no sería un JSON válido, los JSON deben de tener sus cadenas entre comillas dobles, los objetos JavaScript pueden tenerlas dobles, simples y no tenerlas, siempre depende de la versión y de la clave/llave en sí.

Comment: Estoy probando la forma de las comillas como en el ejemplo pero el json queda `mesano"[{\"dia\":\"01-08-2016\",\"X\":\"3\",\"Y\":\"3\",\"A\":\"38\",\"L\":\"30\",\"T\":\"34\"}]"`

Comment: ¿Qué es eso de 'mesano'? ¿Es otra cadena que concatenas al JSON?

Comment: Se estaba generando como objeto de php al parecer, recibí `mesano"{dia:'01-08-2016',X:'0',Y:'5',A:'38',L:'31',T:'35'}"`, use un substring en la función js para poder obtener `{dia:'01-08-2016',X:'0',Y:'5',A:'38',L:'31',T:'35'}` y ahí pude crear el objeto json para recorrer la data.